# simple request.form is causing errorhandler instead of signing in

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-login

when attempting to sign in to the index.html page using the relevant username and password, the errorhandler is activated leading to 404.html, instead of the sign in being accepted or an incorrect username and password message. this occurs whether the correct sign in is used or not.

any advice on what I'm missing or doing wrong?

should I be using request.form.get or request.form.post instead?

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
@app.errorhandler(500)
def errorpage(e):
    return render_template('404.html')

def login_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        if 'logged_in' in session:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            flash('please login first.')
            return redirect (url_for('index'))
    return wrap



@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    error = None
    if  request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['username'] != 'admin' or request.form['password'] != 'password':
            error = 'invalid attempt.'

        else:
            session['logged_in'] = True
            return redirect(url_for('admin'))
    return render_template('index.html', error = error)

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.pop('logged_in', None)
    return render_template('/logout.html')

@app.route('/admin',methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def admin():
```

here is the associated index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"              
<header>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/bootstrap.min.css" media='screen'>
    <title>Login</title>
    <h1>Welcome!</h1>
    <h2>Sign in</h2>
</header>
<body>
    <form action="/helloflask.py" method="post">
        Username: <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" value="{{ request.form.username }}"><br>
        Password: <input type="text" placeholder="Password"  name="password" value="{{ request.form.password }}"><br><br><br>
        <input class= "btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Confirm">


    </form>
    {% if error %}
        <p class="error"><strong>Error:</strong> {{ error }} </p>
    {% endif %}

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `action` attribute of form should be the endpoint which deal with the login function. In this case, You should replace `helloflask.py` with `/`.